# Изменение сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Помогите, не пойму как реализовать изменение сообщения ботом, при ответе на его сообщение словом "измени" он бы изменял написанное им сообщение

```
import telebot
import datetime
import logging

token = '' 

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

# лого в файл
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('bot.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'изменить')
def edit_message(message):
    # Идентификатор канала для редактирования сообщения
    channel_id = ''

    # Новый текст для сообщения
    new_text = 'Измененное сообщение'

    # Редактирование существующего сообщения в канале
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=channel_id, message_id=message.reply_to_message.message_id, text=new_text)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def forward_message(message):
    # Идентификаторы чатов для пересылки сообщений
    source_chat_id = '-'
    destination_chat_id = '-'

    # Слово, которое нужно удалить из сообщения
    target_word = 'Два'

    if target_word in message.text:
        # Удаление целевого слова из сообщения
        modified_text = message.text.replace(target_word, '')

        # Формирование сообщения для пересылки
        forwarded_message = f"{message.from_user.first_name} из чата {message.chat.title} переслал сообщение:\n{modified_text}"

        # Отправка отредактированного сообщение в целевой чат
        bot.send_message(destination_chat_id, forwarded_message)

bot.polling()
```